# z-index effect the anchor tag and anchor tag is not pointing when mouse over

Tags: html, css

My question is very simple, but unfortunately i did not get the way to out, i make a div and its position is relative and also make another div as an absolute and it contains anchor tag, and gave it z-index -1 or -99 it went down, when i mouse over them it did not pointing just simple cursor is there...?  please help me out Thanks.

```
    <div class="parent">                        
        <div class="child">
            <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
            <a href="#" class="rss"></a>
            <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: dear @SableFoste this is my css  .parent{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
 }
 
 .child{
  position: absolute;
  width:25%;
  z-index:-1;
 }

Comment: dear Mani, in the future try to provide the minimal needed code to reproduce the issue. This is what you gave us so far: http://jsbin.com/berecu/1/edit

Comment: dear @SableFoste thanks for your kind attention. actually i am not giving any data in anchor tag, i just made a class inside the anchor tag..!

Comment: There is the problem.  You have to have a 0x0px element.  It can't be hovered over, because it has no height or width.

Comment: can i send u my screenshot that will be better to under stand the issue..

Comment: @Mani believe it or not you should paste some code. I repeat, the minimal code to reproduce the issue. Use developer console, inspect your element play with styles in the right panel and you'll find and fix your error in no-time.